# Effeciently transfer large amount of byte data from C++ to Java

Tags: java, image, java-native-interface

I have a Java program which is designed to display images in a custom file format, read through a C++ library using [JNI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Native_Interface). The data is loaded into an char array on the C++ side, and transferred to a BufferedImage on the Java side. Since sections of the image could be removed from memory and need to be reloaded fairly regularly, so I want these operations to be as fast as possible.

The way I'm currently doing this is data gets read from the file into a buffer in the C++ library's memory. In order to populate the BufferedImage, the Java code makes a JNI function call for each pixel to read from this buffer and, if necessary, load another chunk of data into the buffer. This works, but with a higher overhead than I'd like.

What I've been planning to do to improve this is pass the BufferedImage object to the C++ code using a JNI call, and make function calls on it from that side. I've been researching JNI as much as I can, but I haven't been able to find out if there's any cost in modifying Java objects from a C++ library which was loaded by the JVM. Is this a good way to implement this, or is there a faster way to transfer large amounts of byte data with JNI?

Comment: A call per pixel sounds awful! That would be billions of calls for the larger images. What about fetching blocks or raster lines (e.g. larger image units) at once? Can raster lines can be read sequentially as packed and avoid additional conversions?

Comment: Yes, lines and blocks can both be read into a buffer on the c++ side. I've done a little bit of optimizing that on the c++ side. The problem is I don't know an efficient way to transfer that data back to java, so I do a separate call on each pixel to read the data out of the c++ buffer.

Comment: @resuerman Can something [WritableRaster.setSamples](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/awt/image/WritableRaster.html#setSamples(int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20double[])) be used? If it can, then it might just be finding a way to (most efficiently) load data into a Java array. Is there a way to pin an array and/or wrap [C++] memory and avoid a [primary] copy? Even with an extra copy operation (C++->Java Array->Raster), it should still greatly reduce the number of JNI calls. Also (and I daresay this sounds "extra clever"), can OpenGL (textures) be used here?

Comment: (I've always assumed that WritableRaster was able to do clever blt-level operations when not needing to convert to the target sample format; but I'm no image expert.)

Comment: That looks like it could definitely help. Thanks! I still would have the issue of populating the java array as efficiently as possible though; I'm assuming c++ calls to the java array methods would be best? OpenGL could be an option, although I'm not sure if it would save time on the transfer. Unless I could access the same OpenGL resources with both C++ and Java, it would only probably provide an improvement in display speed, which isn't really an issue. If I could handle the memory solely through OpenGL though, that would probably be most efficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most efficient way to move data across the JNI boundary is probably via direct `ByteBuffers.` You should move as much as you can at a time, as it is crossing the boundary itself that is inefficient, not the transfer. Certainly more than one pixel, preferably megabytes at a time.

Comment: Awesome. This sounds like exactly what I was looking for. Thank you.